# Updating chart on AJAX success

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts

I have created a pie chart using Google charts and some dynamic info that comes from a query as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Customers', 'Status'],
      ['Accepted',     <?php echo $rowsaccepted ;?>],
      ['Declined',      <?php echo $rowsdeclined;?>],
      ['Not Reviewed',  <?php echo $rowsnreview;?>]
    ]);

    var options = {
                   'width':200,
                   'height':200,
                   'backgroundColor':'#474747',
                   'legend': 'none',
                   'chartArea':{left:20,top:0,width:250,height:250},
                   colors: ['#ef8200', '#007fc2', '#41cf0f'],
                   fontSize:14,

               };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

As you can see Im echoing three variables to populate the chart. These three variables are defined in another include where the related query lives and Id like to have the chart  update when the variables are updated, which is done via an AJAX call as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".accept").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var order_id = element.attr("data-order");
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "accept.php",
   //data: info,
   data: {id:del_id,order_id:order_id}
});
});
</script>
```

The two variables that are passed to the AJAX call relate to a rowid and a related name that  the query uses to update a table, which in-turn updates the three variables that populate the chart.

Since my AJAX call is already executed from a button, is there a way I can add a function that will redraw the chart on the success of the AJAX call?

Comment: You can redraw the chart using the `success` callback available as an option param for `$.ajax`. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: ...so literally just make the chart a function and execute it on the success of my AJA call?

Comment: Yep, that is one way to go it. :) I suggest validating the response so that you can handle errors or bad data, but yeah.